# Build Ansible inventory based on server variables

Tags: ansible

I want to build ansible inventory and assign hosts to respective groups based on the values gathered from  Clients.

> Eg: Information of all the clients and their respective group will be
>   pushed to ansible server every night in the below format.

**File Format**

```
Hostgroup1,Hostname1
Hostgroup1,Hostname2
Hostgroup1,Hostname3
Hostgroup2,Hostname1
Hostgroup2,Hostname2
```

From the content of above file i need to create ansible inventory

Comment: what have you tried ? what is the expected output ? Ansible work with Yaml put can accept other format.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options you can use here.

1) Write a script which takes those files and generates the "inventory file" format that ansible uses. Then run that script on a cron job or something after all the uploads take place.

2) Write a script which generates output format complying with the [Ansible inventory JSON format](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#script-conventions), and use it as such: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/inventory/script.html

3) Use the [`add_host`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html) task type as the very first task in your playbook ([with a `localhost` host](https://www.tricksofthetrades.net/2017/10/02/ansible-local-playbooks/)) with a loop to add the hosts.

```
add_host:
  name: "{{ item.hostname }}"
  groups: "{{ item.group }}"
with_items: "{{ somehow inject your list here }}"
```